# Excel Ignores Setting IndentLevel from vb.net

Tags: excel, vb.net

I have a VB.NET app that is controlling Excel. No matter how I attempt to set the `IndentLevel` of a cell, it doesn't stick. Even though subsequent calls to get the `IndentLevel` shows that it did stick, when control is passed back to the user, the cell does not visibly show indentation and right click-> Format Cells, Alignment doesn't show the new value.

I've tried setting `IndentLevel = newValue`, looping on `AddIndent()`, looping on `InsertIndent`, and setting `InsertIndent(newValue)`.

```vb
Dim currCell As Excel.Range = activeWorksheet.Range("B2")
Dim newIndent As Integer
Do While currCell.Row <= activeWorksheet.Cells.SpecialCells(Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
    newIndent = currCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
    If newIndent > 0 Then
         currCell.IndentLevel = newIndent
    End If
    currCell = currCell.Offset(1, 0)
Loop
```

What's maddening is that the VBA equivalent works just fine:

```vb
Sub test()
    Dim currCell As Excel.Range
    Set currCell = ActiveSheet.Range("B2")

    Dim newIndent As Integer
    Do While currCell.Row <= ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
        newIndent = currCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
        If newIndent > 0 Then
            currCell.IndentLevel = newIndent
        End If
        Set currCell = currCell.Offset(1, 0)
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: The VB.NET and VBA codes are not really equivalent. `ActiveSheet` dynamically tracks the actual active sheet, while your `activeWorksheet` variable does not. Insert a `MsgBox(currCell.Address(External:=True))` in that loop.

Comment: @GSerg, that did not change the behavior.  What was the thinking there?

Comment: @Dan To verify that you are trying to affect the right cells on the right sheet in the right workbook.

Comment: @GSerg - I had a similar thought.  I updated the code to modify the cell contents with the "new" indentation level.  The proper cell values update as expected.  What's even crazier, is that Excel is reporting the NEW IndentionLevel, even though the graphics don't show it!  Here's the new line I put after the indent is set:
`currCell.Value = currCell.Value & "(" & currCell.IndentLevel & ")"`

Comment: Have a VBA macro in that Excel file that reports the indent level from VBA side. Call that macro from VB.NET after setting  IndentLevel from VB.NET (`Application.Run("that macro")`). If it reports differently (and you have certainly verified that it is the same cell), then the .NET wrapper is apparently caches that value and reports the cached value, but does not propagate it to Excel.